# Rest download file 204 No Content

Tags: java, resteasy

I have a simple rest service that should be downloaded to a png image.

Here's the code:

```
@POST() 
@Path(value= "/download")

@Produces( {"image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/tiff"} )
@Consumes( {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML} )
public Response downloadImage(ChatDownloadFileRequest input) {
        ResponseBuilder response = null;            
        Image img = (Image)em2.createNamedQuery("Image.findByMessageId")
                      .setParameter("messageId", request.getMessageId())
                      .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
                      .getSingleResult();

            String imgPath = img.getPath();

            File file = new File( imgPath );

            response = Response.ok((Object)file);

            String fileName = file.getName();
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            return response.build(); 
}
```

When I make a call the answer is 204 No Content.

Thanks to all

Regards.

Comment: Can you confirm that the file exist on the path specified? Something like `if (!file.exists()) syso("stuff")`

Comment: I don't think you can just put a `File` in your response and hope the binary content comes out with the correct mimetype.  I'm guessing jax-rs doesn't know how to handle the File and is sending null by default.

Comment: Yes, the file exist, and i tried to put into response a FileInputStream but the same response.